# What is a 7-2 ruling in legal context?

Tags: legalese

> "Although his court challenge (Eldred vs. Attorney General John Ashcroft) was turned down by a United States circuit court, many believed that the lower court's decision had a very good chance of being overturned. However, in January 2003, the U.S. Supreme Court upheld the earlier decision in a 7-2 ruling." - (Spinello, A., and H. Tavani, Intellectual Property Rights in a Networked World, p. 186)

What is the meaning of a 7-2 ruling?

Answer (score 6):

This is a common turn of phrase to mean that the Supreme Court, comprised of 9 judges, reached the decision with 7 judges voting for it and 2 against.

You can see it, for example, in the New York Times' review of the US Supreme Court's 2015 decisions, with each decision's yay/nay ratio expressed as X-Y:

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/us/major-supreme-court-cases-in-2015.html